# Laravel check if JWT token exists

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am using this [package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for token authentication in Laravel. In my controller I would like to check if the token exists

```
public function show(Article $article)
    {
        $article->media = $article->media;
        $article->externalMedia;

        if (JWTAuth token exists) {
            $this->addUserSpecificData($article);
        }


        return $article;
    }
```

But not sure how to do this?

Comment: I know you're asking for a way to check if the JWT token exists but wouldn't it be better to check if the user is authenticated? If you do that you can use `Auth::user()` to access the currently authenticate user model and get all the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$currentUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

Comment: I can't because it is throwing invalid token exception